# How can I provide a methods implementation using Moq?

Tags: c#, nunit, integration-testing, moq

I have an interface with a few methods. I have a default implementation of this interface. For the purpose of integration tests I would like to create a mock implementation that returns my custom value if one of these methods is called, and falls back to the default implementation otherwise. Is it possible with Moq, or should I create a simple stub myself?

EXAMPLE

```
IInterface default = new DefaultImplementation();
var mock = new Mock<IInterface>();
mock.Setup(i => i.Method(It.IsAny<>())).Calls(p => p==0 ? return 5 : default.Method(p););

TheMethodITest(mock.Object()); //if it calls the object with 0 then it should get 5, otherwise it should call the default object
```

Comment: Can you provide a code example?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean with *and falls back to the default implementation otherwise*. When can this method be triggered if it's not called?

Comment: @Ian, added example using non-existent methods to the question

Comment: You can prevent this situation altogether by splitting it over multiple tests. It's obvious that testing the unit with a certain input will trigger something different than other inputs so it is definitely okay to separate them.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, this is for the purpose of integration tests. `TheMethodITest` will call other methods, and pass the `IInterface` around, and the method `Method` will be called multiple times in different places. We already have unit tests in place, now we want to see it all works together.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the condition for providing default or your specific value. However, it sounds like you want to set up a mock instance with `Delegator`.

```
public void MoqCanBeSetupWithDelegator()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IInterface>();
    Func<string, int> valueFunction = i => i == "true" ? 1 : default(int);
    mock.Setup(x => x.Method(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(valueFunction);

    Assert.Equal(1, mock.Object.Method("true"));
    Assert.Equal(0, mock.Object.Method("anonymous"));
}

public interface IInterface
{
    int Method(string arg);
}
```

As you can see, the `Returns` method is overloaded to accept a returned value(`int`) or delegator representing the mocked method signature. You can use `Func<string, int>` to replace the  actual implementation - `int Method(string arg)`.

Comment: Furthermore, it is not intuitive to implement this function inline.  To achieve this you need to specify the types of the parameters in the lambda expression.  For example `...Returns( (string i) => i == "true" ? 1 : default(int) );`  Without specifying `(string i)` the compiler cannot tell which method overload you are trying to call.

Comment: What if the method "returns" void? There is no `Returns()` method then... :(

Comment: Wonderful. Just used this kind of code to produce test mock of a big repo, where I just needed to wire a few of the method method calls through into a much smaller/simpler in memory repo... Without having to stub out all the other methods the interface required..   with a method like: IBigRepository CreateMock(SmallInMemoryRepository inner)

Answer (score 14):

You can do this, by setting the Mock to the concrete class and using `As()` to retrieve the underlying `IInterface`, on which the setup is done. You can then hard cast `mock.Object` to invoke the underlying concrete object:

```
  [Test]
  public void SomeTest()
  {
     var mock = new Mock<DefaultImplementation>().As<IInterface>();
     mock.Setup(i => i.Method(It.IsAny<int>()))
         .Returns<int>(p => p == 0 
                                 ? 5 
                                 : ((DefaultImplementation)mock.Object).Method(p));

     TheMethodITest(mock.Object);
  }
```

Here's the rest of the setup I tested with, FWIW:

```
public interface IInterface
{
   int Method(int p);
}
public class DefaultImplementation : IInterface
{
   public int Method(int p)
   {
      return 6;
   }
}
[TestFixture]
public class SomeFixture
{
   public static void TheMethodITest(IInterface dep)
   {
      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
         Debug.WriteLine("{0}:{1}",i, dep.Method(i));
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not plug `DefaultImplementation` directly into the method instead of wrapping it in a Moq?

Comment: @StuartLC: Doesn't one need to use `CallBase`?

Comment: @JohnGietzen Indeed, it is easier like that: `new Mock<DefaultImplementation>() { CallBase = true }.As<IInterface>();`